# ExtJS: Preventing Checkboxes inheriting the hideLabel attribute of their parent CheckboxGroup

Tags: extjs, checkbox

I am trying to display checkboxes within checkboxgroups. To keep them lined up with the other fields in the form, I want to disable the group's `fieldLabel`, while keeping each checkbox's individual `fieldLabel`. However, if I set `hideLabel` to `true` for the checkboxgroup, the field labels for the individual checkboxes disappear also, even if I explicitly set `hideLabel` to `false`.

Is this going to be possible? Thanks for any help.

Edit: As requested, some code:

```
config = {
    xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
    hideLabel: true,
    columns: 1,
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'Item 1', 
        hideLabel: false
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Item 2', 
        hideLabel: false
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using some custom CSS. Instead of setting `display: none` to any label elements that are descendants of a container with the `x-hide-label` class, it is only applied to labels that are direct children of such a container.

```
.x-hide-label label.x-form-item-label {
    display: inline;
}

.x-hide-label > label.x-form-item-label {
    display: none;
}
```

It's not perfect, but it works for me. Checkboxes and their labels remain aligned properly with all other form elements.

Answer (score 0):

Are you defining a boxLabel on the checkboxes?   You should define the boxLabels on the combos and set hideLabel to true on the checkboxgroup.

Comment: I did not want to use boxLabel as I would prefer the checkboxes labelled as the other form fields are labelled: with the fieldLabel to the left and the field itself to the right. Also, I have no use for a fieldLabel on the group itself. I will use this if I can find no other solution, it's just not "perfect".

Comment: You can use the boxAlign property to place the label exactly where you wish.  It's also possible to not use the fieldLabel or boxLabel properties at all and just use the Ext.form.Label objects instead.

Comment: I can find no reference anywhere to a boxAlign property, and using Ext.form.Label objects separately display the label and the checkbox on separate lines, as they are individual items within the checkboxgroup.

Comment: I remember using it in the past... I'm not able to find it in the current API doc...